# Mysql database backup from one xampp folder to another

Tags: mysql, xampp

I forgot to opt export database option and install the xampp again. Now how can I take backup from the old xampp folder, I have the older xampp folder as backup?

What I tried- I just copied the folder of my database to the data folder, but I got the following error-
Can't find file: 'mytablename' (errno: 2)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `basedir` and  `datadir` in my.ini/my.cnf. If the path is configured correctly. then try this

---

```
 shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data &
```

2. Ensure that you have proper permissions

   ```
   shell> chown -R mysql
   shell> chgrp -R mysql
   ```

Finally, use this

```
  shell> mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

Comment: can you tell me the process on windows-7, I found basedir and  datadir path is configured correctly. Can you explain this- Can't find file: 'mytablename' (errno: 2)